# Fix for orphan user 'guest'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What can be done, if anything, when the special `guest` user is orphaned (not linked to any login)?

For one of my databases (SQL Server 2005), executing the following lists the **guest** user as an orphaned user.

```
exec sp_change_users_login 'report'
```

Results:

```
UserName    UserSID
guest       0x3C2E66759FFBC14F84127D6795C27FD3
```

If I try to fix the **guest** user using that procedure, I get the following:

```
exec sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'guest', 'guest'
```

> Terminating this procedure. 'guest' is a forbidden value for the
>   login name parameter in this procedure.

If I try to delete the user, I get:

> User 'guest' cannot be dropped, it can only be disabled.

```
select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'guest'
```

Results in:

```
name                 guest
principal_id         2
type                 S
type_desc            SQL_USER
default_schema_name  guest
create_date          11/13/98 2:58 AM
modify_date          10/16/01 4:31 PM
owning_principal_id  NULL
sid                  0x3C2E66759FFBC14F84127D6795C27FD3
is_fixed_role        0
```

The database seems to be confused as to whether this is a special user or not. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Its SID is listed as `0x3C2E66759FFBC14F84127D6795C27FD3` instead of `0x00`

Comment: Have you tried to do the auto fix yet? I'm curious to see the result.

Comment: I get `Terminating this procedure. 'guest' is a forbidden value for the login name parameter in this procedure.`

Comment: You get that error because you can't have guest as the user name (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx).  I am having a hard time recreating your scenario.

Comment: I understand that. I'm not sure how `guest` happened to get into this state, but noticed it in doing some db maintenance. It may not be important enough to worry about, but would be curious to know if there's an answer.

Comment: Your guest user isn't the special guest user: it has been remapped or aliased or something. I can't mimic this (SQL Server 2012). Is this database an upgraded one from SQL Server 2000 or earlier? For example, did someone change sys.users previously?

Comment: I am unsure how the user came to be this way--it's possible it happened some time ago through an upgrade or other process.

Comment: @JustinStolle If you've not yet resolved this on your own, there are a couple of things that would help us help you. 1) Could please tell us what changes were made prior to this occurring. Did you migrate data? 2) Can you query `syslogins` and see if there is an entry for `guest` in there? Thanks

Comment: @swasheck I'm afraid I don't know what prior changes were made as I merely happened to notice this while doing unrelated user maintenance. It could have existed for a very long time for all I know. There is no login named guest in `master.dbo.syslogins`.

Comment: What is the value of `principal_id` for the guest user when you run `select * from sys.database_principals`?

Comment: The `principal_id` of guest is `2`

Comment: A stored procedure to remap orphan users. http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/11/sql-server-how-to-remap-existing.html

Comment: The procedure will attempt to do what I've already tried, which failed, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'd like to add that I encountered exactly the same issue as Justin did. The problem here is the sid of guest should be 0x00 but for whatever reason, it is not and as such sp_change_users_login 'report' will pick it up as an orphaned user. I just cannot see that there is a way for DBAs to change or mess [guest] sid in normal ways. So I'd think this mess is highly possible created by sql server patches sometime, somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user "guest" is never assigned to a server login, even on a fresh install it is classified as a SQL user without a login. As you can only set the SID of a login (upon creation), and not a user I don't believe that this is possible; sp_change_users_login does not work precisely for the reason that the guest account should never be mapped to a server login. As a result, the user "guest" is always an orphaned user. Probably not the answer you wanted though :)

Comment: Do you think there is a way to backup/restore this database to another location while leaving out the guest user from the restore?

Comment: Yes but it's not pretty. A simple backup and restore would not work as the guest user would be included in that. You would need to start with a fresh database created using the same method you used to install it originally (assuming the guest in model has the correct SID). Then from your existing system export all the data into your new database. This would work, but it is a lot of effort for something so minor...

Comment: So despite the account having an unexpected SID, you think there isn't really a problem with it and it's safe to ignore it in the `sp_change_users_login` report?

Comment: In this instance I would say so, based on the fact that there isn't really that much you can actually do about it anyway. Then there's the classic debate about whether you should/shouldn't be using it anyway, but that's a different question entirely... :)

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts...
The reason `sp_change_users_login` is throwing that error is because MS wrote it too. [Looking through system procedure code every now and then can be fun. :)] However the fact that it shows up when running the report is indicating that someone/some process messed with the account, or a possible hot fix from MS could have done it (you never know).

The guest account is supposed to be there, it exist in every database that is created since the account exist in model by default. Making it not show up in the report would probably require getting that SID changed back to `0x00` I would guess. As long as the account is disabled I would leave it alone and ignore it. If it was really bothering me though I would fork out the money and put a call in with Microsoft support.

Comment: In other words, you are saying it isn't a problem that `guest` shows up in the results in this case.

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> Note : Whenever you move your database from one server to another
>   server there is a problem of orphan user usually occur. FileListOnly
>   is the new term in sql server that has all the details of the created
>   backup that who has access to it.

So there are sequence of task that you have to follow

> 1. Firstly you have to restore the FileListOnly from the created backup to the destination or new server.
> 2. Restore the backup.
> 3. Use the sp_change_users_login  as per the need. For help regarding this procedure you can refer
>      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx.

I put a example here hope it will help:

```
> RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\YourDB.bak'
> 
> RESTORE DATABASE YourDb FROM DISK = N'C:\YourDB.bak' WITH MOVE
> N'YourDB' TO N'D:\YourDB.mdf', MOVE N'YourDB_log' TO N'D:\YourDB.ldf',
> REPLACE
> 
> exec YourDB.dbo.sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'UserName','UserName'
```

Comment: This won't work for the `guest` user. See answer above by Mr.Brownstone.